# Unable to access secondary OS (Windows)

Tags: linux, windows, dualboot

I currently have three storage devices on my PC: nvme1n1(windows OS), sda1(windows storage) and nvme01n1(Artix Linux(runit))

I am able to access the Artix installation fully and do what I want. However I am unable to do anything with my Windows installation. To be clear windows is on its own separate SSD and HDD.

When in Artix I am able to list the other partitions with fdisk however I am unable to edit or access them any further than this.

When loading into the BIOS which has worked for me before on previous "dual boots" I am only able to boot into my Artix installation. When attempting to boot into the windows installation via BIOS I get the message "This is not a bootable disk. Please insert a bootable floppy..."

I have used the Windows installation for hundreds of hours previous to installing Artix. However I have not been able to access it since installing Artix.

I'm not highly tech literate so if there is anymore information needed please let me know.

Comment: Can you please add the output of `fdisk -l` for both drives? Preferably also the output of `lsblk -f` and `efibootmgr`.

Comment: @TomYan this is the output for all command's mentioned. https://imgur.com/a/SWSEHHL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how it happened, but it appears that the partition table of your Windows OS drive has been converted from DOS/MBR style to GPT style. Because it's an old installation that has BIOS variant of Windows Boot Manager which works only with the former style, so it is expectedly unbootable.

You either need to convert it back (and make sure the MBR has required boot code and the right partition has the active flag), or you can simply install a set of UEFI variant of Windows Boot Manager (WBM) to your EFI system partition on your Linux drive.

The latter would allow you to boot Windows from efi grub, but your Windows will become unbootable again in case you remove the Linux drive, until you install a set of UEFI WBM to somewhere appropriate again.

You may want to research on `bootsect.exe` (for "reinstalling" MBR boot code AFTER fixing your partition table), OR, `bcdboot.exe` (for installing UEFI WBM). I'm not sure if the former is still available on modern Windows ISO, but there's some Linux alternative called ms-sys on sourceforge anyway.

I don't remember if there's any tool on Linux which allows you to convert GPT to DOS/MBR partition table in "one-click" without erasing any data, but the bottom line is you can always recreate from scratch with the same starting and ending sector with `fdisk`. Just make sure you say NO whenever it asks you whether you want to wipe data on the partitions.

**WARNING: BACKUP BACKUP BACKUP; NO GUARANTEE OR WARRANTY FROM ME; FIXING THIS SORT OF PROBLEM IS ALWAYS DANGEROUS TO A CERTAIN EXTENT**